# Payone getting the transaction list "history"

Tags: php, payone

How Can I get the transaction history via Payone server API  "'https://api.pay1.de/post-gateway"

Is there any request command to achieve that ?

I've checked their [API docs](https://docs.payone.com/display/public/PLATFORM/Request+Overview) but couldn't find any request to get the transactions log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work for PAYONE. Unfortunately, there is currently no possibility to request the transaction history. If you have any further questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Not even a single transaction ?  Or the transaction status of the recurring payments?